# How to properly link classes, so I can use it's methods in other classes?

Tags: java, swing

so I'm still a newbie to all this Java and Swing GUI thing. I switch between the panels from time to time and pretty much all of them has a Back button to go back to the main panel. The problem is, the method that I use to switch to that panel is in my main GUI class, if you can call that and I create an ActionListener in GUIUtils class, where I have all different methods to create stuff in the UI, so I don't need to rewrite everything every single time. The problem is, I asked for help from ChatGPT and I kind of understood how it works, but right now, I understand that I don't. So I would appreciate the help to make it right.

I will just give you a few CodeBlocks that would recreate the problem.

My main GUI class has this method

```
public void switchToMainMenu() {
        getContentPane().remove(cardManager.getPanel());
        add(createMainMenu(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
```

Which, right now, isn't really flexible, but for my app, it does the job. Because at the moment, I really only have one panel, that has a Back button, so this code deletes that panel, and adds a main menu panel.

And this is a snippet from my GUIUtils class. I create a BackButtonActionListener with a reference, I think that's the right word for it, to the GUI class, so that it can use it's method. And a getter for it, not sure if it's a 100% needed, but without it, it won't work.

```java
public static class BackButtonAction implements ActionListener {
        private final GUI interfaceAssociation;

        public BackButtonAction(GUI gui) {
            this.interfaceAssociation = gui;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            interfaceAssociation.switchToMainMenu();
        }
    }

    public static ActionListener getBackButtonAction(GUI gui) {
        return new BackButtonAction(gui);
    }
```

And lastly, my CardManager panel's creation of a button

```java
JButton backButton = GUIUtils.createButton("Back", GUIUtils.getBackButtonAction(new GUI()));
```

As I understand, I create a new GUI in it instead of passing a reference to it. I understood that and I fixed by passing a reference to the GUI class in the CardManager's constructor, not sure if those are the right words for it.

```java
private GUI gui;

    public CardManager(GUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }
```

And creating a button like this

```java
JButton backButton = GUIUtils.createButton("Back", GUIUtils.getBackButtonAction(gui));
```

So, what I wanna know, is this the only way to do it, or is there a more elegant, right method to do something like this?

Comment: *Two of those work perfectly fine* - which two? *But one of them* - which one? How is the code different between the two that work and the one that doesn't? That is what debugging is about. The code you posted doesn't help because you use 3rd party classes. When asking a question post a proper [mre]. Also, there is no need for a "CardManager" class. To swap panels you should be using a [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Answering the question in your title, you create an instance of the panel class and get the `JPanel` instance using a panel class getter.

Comment: @camickr It is called CardManager because there will be some other functionality, buttons and etc., not because I manage the layout with it. For a Layout Manager I'm using MigLayout. I added more code and a bit more explanation of what happens.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's exactly what I did, I think. I created an instance of CardManager in GUI class. CardManager class has a getter method, which just returns the main panel of the CardManager class. And then in switchToSettingsMenu method of GUI class, I call add function ```cardManager = new CardManager();
        add(cardManager.getPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);```, but before that I remove the mainMenu panel. Unless I'm not doing it the right way?

Comment: 1) The "CardLayout" should be the top level layout manager. It is used to swap panels. The MigLayout can be used on individual panels. Did you read the tutorial for a working example? 2) You still haven't stated which buttons work and which don't and what the code difference is? 3) Still haven't posted an [mre]. An MRE should be a single class that simulates the problem you are describing. We are not interest in the entire application. The tutorial I linked to has an MRE for you to understand and modify to meet your requirements.

Comment: @camickr BorderLayout should work fine, too, no?  Which is used as a top level layout manager. MigLayout is only used for other panels. I have stated which buttons work and which don't. And there's no code difference in how I'm switching between panels. And I don't see how a single class example would help here, because maybe the problem lies in how I'm getting stuff FROM ANOTHER CLASS. As per my understanding, it should be fine, but as I have already stated, I'm new and still figuring stuff out, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: So you still haven't read the CardLayout tutorial have you??? Yes, the frame uses a BorderLayout. The CardLayout is used on the panel holding the panels you want to swap. Read the tutorial and download the test code. That is how you learn. Start from a working example.  *I have stated which buttons work and which don't* - finally. *there's no code difference in how I'm switching between panels* - what??? Have you actually looked at the methods "switchToGame" and "switchToSettingsMenu"? They look different to me.

Comment: *the problem lies in how I'm getting stuff FROM ANOTHER CLASS* - once you understand how CardLayout works you can simply use the `getParent()` method of the child panels to access the panel using the CardLayout. Then you use the CardLayout to swap panels. But first you need to understand how to use CardLayout.

Comment: Okey, let's say I use the CardLayout, but that still doesn't do anything good for me, because I want to understand what's exactly wrong with my own method. Like, I appreciate the help, but right now you're just saying use that, not this, but not explaining why this doesn't work. And now I really did read through the CardLayout tutorial and while it seems easier, I still want to understand what I did wrong with my own method. Because switching to gamePanel works fine, but not to cardManager.

Comment: And I really don't see how those two methods are different, they both do the same thing, they both have same lines. The only difference is in which panels they add. And both panel classes, have the same getters method. Just returns a panel specific to the class. Even constructors for both classes are technically the same. So I really don't see, how you look at that and see two completely different methods, to be honest. I really appreciate the help, but right now you're just poking with that only method, like it's the only method you can do, not really explaining why my method doesn't work.

Comment: And I already told you I can't help because you haven't posted an [mre]. You posted incomplete blocks of code an expect us to understand it. It doesn't work that way.  It is NOT easy to visualize the GUI in our heads to see what happens when one button is clicked vs another button. We need to be able to debug the code to see how it works. Notice how no other person has commented? That is because you haven't made it easy to answer the question without the MRE.

Comment: Again you issue is with the swapping of panels when you click a button. The logic behind the game is irrelevant. The [mre] should be a simple version of your application that simply swaps panels. You have been given a working example from the tutorial showing the concept of an MRE. Take time to create your own if you want help with your design. And as I stated the MigLayout is a 3rd party class is irrelevant to the concept of swapping panels, unless maybe it is the reason why it doesn't work? So the MRE should use standard JDK classes.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you keep creating a new instance of the CardManager class. Maybe the reference to the "cardManager" variable is not what you expect because the methods that create and then reference the variable are not in the order you think. I would only ever create a single instance of the CardManager class.

Comment: @camickr Thank you and sorry if I came out rude. Actually, trying to create an MRE helped find the problem. I rewrote the whole post, only providing code blocks, which were problematic and I would really like to know if the way I'm doing it is right or should I do it another way?

Comment: No it is NOT an MRE. We can't copy/paste/compile/test code blocks. I've already told you that the tutorial link provides a simple example of an MRE with all the logic in one file.

Comment: You’re right, it’s not minimal variant, but complete, which is mentioned in the link you provided. I left code blocks, snippets of the code of each file, which is mentioned that you can do, where I need more help understanding how it should be done the right way. And I tried to provide as much information as possible in the text.